# ¿Cómo levantar app rails en red local?

Tags: linux, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hola quiero hacer una aplicacion para ser usada dentro de la empresa, por lo que no necesito usar heroku ni nada por el estilo. Solo quiero que se acceda desde dentro de la red interna. 
Supongo que hay otra forma ademas de dejar la consola corriendo con rails server en el servidor.

¿Cómo se puede hacer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Efectivamente, puedes usar apache o nginx para levantar una aplicación rails de forma permanente para lograr la compatibilidad puedes usar passenger o unicorn.

Estas guías pueden servirte:

- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-unicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04
- https://coderwall.com/p/yz8cha/deploying-rails-app-using-nginx-unicorn-postgres-and-capistrano-to-digital-ocean
- http://nmajor.com/ubuntu-server-setup-rvm-nginx-unicorn/

Basicamente los pasos a seguir son :

- Instalar nginx
- Instalar unicorn
- Configurar nginx y unicorn
- Reiniciar nginx

Una vez tengas el servidor levantado debes solo acceder localmente a la ip del servidor.

Answer (score 0):

rails s -p 8080 -h localhost
el 8080 es el puerto que deseas utilizar para que corra tu servidor. Suponiendo que el servidor tiene la ip 192.168.1.2 entonces solo necesitarias entrar desde otro equipo que este en la lan a 192.168.1.2:8080