# ¿Como puedo levantar mi aplicación Ruby on Rails de un servidor local? con Windows 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tengo una aplicación hecha con Ruby 3.0.0 y Rails 7.1, y necesito entregarla y levantarla en una red local en una computadora que posee Windows 10. Solo quiero que se acceda desde dentro de la red interna

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo levantar app rails en red local?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/44464/213)

Comment: Tu pregunta ha sido cerrada como duplicada. Si consideras que tu pregunta es distinta a la otra, debes [edit] tu pregunta y señalar claramente en que se diferencia

Comment: y el código? siempre agrega un [mcve]